# A better way to compare arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering a better way to compare the values of an array, something different to the current I am doing.

For code like below, is it possible to use case statement?

```
uint8_t array[8];

if (array[4] == '1' && array[5] == '2' && array[6] == 'b' && array[7] == 'c')
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: you mean '&&' not '&'

Comment: std::array is not available for me.

Comment: `strncmp(array+4, "12bc")` might work. But it's not going to be any faster.

Comment: Bummer. `switch`/`case` won't be much help for this job, but you may find the [somewhat related Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) helpful in the future.

Comment: 'std::array is not available for me`  It is depressing how often nominal C++ instructors forbid using C++. https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk  Can you use std::begin and std::end?  Or are you required to write pure C code?

Comment: @Jive, you jump to a conclusion. You're likely right, but Asker may be tasked with maintaining a legacy codebase and be restricted to using GCC 3.3.

Comment: @user4581301 -  My phone buzzed for this? This questioner is not in charge of maintaining legacy code.

Comment: whether `std::array` is available is mostly irrelevant to this question

Comment: my 10c. This code is efficient and its intent is clear. The strncmp type magics only work for contiguous bytes.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you need to use the logical AND operator, `&&`, not the bitwise AND operator, `&`.

Second, you can use [`std::memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) instead of using four logical expressions in the `if` statement.

```
if ( std::memcmp(array + 4, "12bc", 4) == 0 )
```

Comment: wow, that is awesome for comparting :) it is very shot and simple, are there more options similar to this?

Comment: @Ale If you were using `std::string` or other C++ stuff, it would just be (roughly) `if (myString == "12bc")`

Comment: @Justin Almost, but the same mistake as I made when pitching `std::array` User's interest in the array starts in the middle.

Comment: @user4581301 True. The fix becomes `std::string_view{myString.c_str() + 4, myString.size() - 4} == "12bc"`, which is admittedly not very terse...

Answer (score 4):

For variety, here's another...

```
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    uint8_t     array[8];

    // fill array

    uint8_t    other[]{ "12b4" } ;
    bool eq = std::equal( std::begin(array) + 4, std::end(array), std::begin(other));

}
```

Comment: Works for any type: C-style arrays, `std::string`, `std::array`, `std::vector`, ...

Comment: It does not look shorter or easier to read than the original `if ( array[4] == '1' && array[5] == '2' ...`.

Answer (score 1):

In short: `if ( !memcmp( array + 4, "12bc", 4 ) )`. Don't think that `strncmp` is better because:

1) `array` is of `uint8_t` not `char`;

2) only 4 bytes are compared and there is no null termination i.e. there is no string comparison.

Comment: I left off the `4` length argument in my suggestion for using `strncmp()`, which does not require the character comparisons to stop at a null character. However, `memcmp()` is probably a better choice.